# Using prototype to ceate a global object

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have an AJAX function that gets JSON response. I want to convert this JSON repsonse into a global object using prototype. I don't have a clear concept of prototyping but I think my idea is correct. Forgive me if I am wrong.

Here is the code

```
var RatesGlobal = {};

$('#tarrif').load("<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/rates/index", function (data) {

    RatesGlobal.prototype.tarrifRates = JSON.parse(data);

});
```

I want to later access the values of the JSON string, forgive me if the question is not clear enough. I don't know if this is the proper usage of prototypes.  What is the right way of doing so ?

Comment: No, my question is not about the response but creating a global object or a variable from the response.

Comment: @Bazinga777 Then simplify the code such that there is no unnecessary `load` involved. The introduction of `load` *only* affects the [a]synchronous nature.

Comment: It doesn't really look like you're getting it? You're using `load()` to fetch JSON, and then for some strange reason you'd like to get that JSON, parse it, and have a global? For what purpose? You know you can't use the JSON until the ajax request is done, and that `load()` inserts content automagically in your HTML ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake in using load, my idea was to create a global object using AJAX. Poor questioning on my part but @Minkos answer is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any prototype. Prototypes are usually used for code reuse.

Use:

```
$('#tarrif').load("<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/rates/index", function (data) {
    window.GLOBAL = JSON.parse(data);
});
```

Access it this way: `window.GLOBAL`.

You can create object, which prototype is the response of your request:

```
$('#tarrif').load("<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/rates/index", function (data) {
    window.GLOBAL = Object.create(JSON.parse(data));
});
```

Anyway, I don't see why you would ever need this.

Comment: totally forgot about the window object. Thanks, but is there a way to do it using protoyping? just curious

Comment: Note that load() is async, and if you don't wait for the response it doesn't matter what you attach it to.

Comment: @Bazinga777 just added example for using prototypes. Anyway, in my opinion it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @MinkoGechev: I am just curious. thanks for showing me the better way of doing it.